# Subscribe to Gazebo Plugin Topic

Tags: ros, python, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a sdf file where I put Gazebo IMU plugin. The gazebo topic is `~/turtlebot/rack/imu_sensor/imu` . How can I create a ROS2 node that subscribes to that Gazebo topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25303/subscribe-to-gazebo-plugin-topic/) by [tasuminagorashi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27915/tasuminagorashi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

you should:

- create a `gazebo::transport::Node` to subscribe the Gazebo topic
- create a ROS 2 node and create the gith publisher.
- In the callback you need to fill the ROS 2 message with the Gazebo IMU message.

Here you can a find a snippet of how to implement this idea.

```
gazebo_ros::Node::SharedPtr ros_node;

rclcpp::Publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>::SharedPtr imu_pub;

gazebo::transport::NodePtr gz_node;

// Function is called everytime a message is received.
void cb(ConstImuPtr &_msg)
{
  gazebo_msgs::msg::IMU imu_msg;
 
 // fill imu_msg message based on _msg
 
  imu_pub->publish(imu_msg);

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  // Load gazebo
  gazebo::client::setup(argc, argv);

  if (!rclcpp::is_initialized()) {
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    ros_node = gazebo_ros::Node::Get();
  } else {
    ros_node = gazebo_ros::Node::Get();
  }

  imu_pub = ros_node->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::Imu>("/turtlebot/rack/imu_sensor/imu", rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(rclcpp::KeepLast(1)));

  // Gazebo transport
  gz_node = gazebo::transport::NodePtr(new gazebo::transport::Node());
  gz_node->Init();

  // Listen to Gazebo world_stats topic
  gazebo::transport::SubscriberPtr sub = gz_node->Subscribe("~/turtlebot/rack/imu_sensor/imu", cb);

  while (true)
    gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(10);

  // Make sure to shut everything down.
  gazebo::client::shutdown();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26408/ahcorde/) with karma: 281 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1